# Return Obj from @RestController

Tags: java, json, angularjs, spring

Greattings!

I have a Spring-MVC Controller that use @RestController to return JsonData ( Spring 4.1.7 ).

My problem is, if I return a List, it works, but if I try to return a single obj, I get an error without trace! It simples doesn't return.

This is how I made the call

```
 $scope.edit = function edit(id) {
 $http.post(urlBase + 'test/edit/'+id).success(function(data) {
     alert('works');
  }).error(function(data) {
      alert('error' + data);
     });

 };
```

And this is the controller

```
  @RestController
  public class MyController {
      @Autowired 
      MyService myService;

  //THIS DOESN'T WORK
      @RequestMapping(value="/secure/test/edit/{id}", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
      public MyObject editObj(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
          return this.myService.getObjById(id);
      }
  //THIS WORKS
      @RequestMapping(value="/secure/test/edit/{id}", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
      public List<MyObject> editObj(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
          return this.myService.getAll();
      }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I'm getting this error

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;])</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;])</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;])
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: sys.barattie.model.Caixa_$$_jvst126_0[&quot;handler&quot;])
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:59)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:26)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1887)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter
```

**UPDATE 2**

Obj Class

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "test")
  public class myObject {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "id")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Integer id;
      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "objb_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
      private Objb objb;
      private String test;

      public Integer getId() {
          return id;
      }
      public void setId(Integer id) {
          this.id = id;
      }
      public Objb getObjb() {
          return objb;
      }
      public void setObjb(Objb objb) {
          this.objb = objb;
      }
      public String getTest() {
          return test;
      }
      public void setTest(String test) {
          this.test = test;
      }
  }
```

Comment: It must return *something*, or throw an exception. And there's no way you get an exception without stack trace. Check the response you get in the network panel of your browser dev tools. Or change your method to GET (that's what they *should* use) and simply enter the URL of your REST service in the browser address bar.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of error you get? Or simply use Chrome Console Developer to look up for POST request, or simply use console.log(data); in js code? and post here what you get?

Comment: How do you know that you are getting an error, if you have no stack trace? If you think in UI you are not getting expected result so there must be an exception, then it is wrong. Use Chrome developers tool or a HTTP debugging client like Fiddler to check that is returned from server.

Comment: Also, check if you have custom setting in one of your configuration file for `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. If so, please provide here for analysis.

Comment: I have mapped all throwable exceptions with and error page, I will comment that mapping to see if I get some trace, after that I'll let you guys know! Thanks !

Comment: Removing mapping has nothing to do with stack trace of exception .. If you really getting exception then it will come whether you have mapped some error codes with some JSP's .. Better debug the HTTP traffic to see what is the response coming and HTTP response code coming the case where you are getting unexpected results ..

Comment: Could you console.log/alert the `id` parameter in your `edit` JS function?

Comment: @sp00m updated again, Yep, I get the id 1 in my alert/log of the parameter.

I also tried to force the id, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Added to my model class the following annotation

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code with my class Object and see it works fine. It seems your class `MyObject` missing something. Maybe missing implements `Serializable`.

Comment: Added my Obj class to the post

Comment: All I need is to implement serializable to my class ?

Like this ?
`public class myObj implements Serializable { ..code.. }`

Comment: Tried, without result.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/secure/test/edit/{id}", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
      public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<MyObject> editObj(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
          return new ResponseEntity<MyObject>(this.myService.getObjById(id),HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

Return **ResponseEntity** object as Spring can easily generate/parse JSON for this.

Comment: @lucas-freitas Create a VO of myObject entity and then set all values from entity to VO. JSON message convertor will not be able to create a JSON string directly from entity as it has ManyToOne relation. Also in general entity classes have two way relationship ie. in one class ManyToOne and in anther class OneToMany, while parsing object using JSON message convertor it does infinite recursive calls between object of both classes. so its a good practice to create a VO and pass it as ResponseBody.

Comment: did you have a example to show me ? I post and answer of what I did to solve the problem, I think that this isn't the best way, but I was pushing the wall to many times

Comment: I don't have any example right now but its always good to follow design patterns. Specially MVC (3-tier architecture) when using spring framework. its always better if we decouple all layers/tiers ie. data tier(JPA classes entity and repository) --> business tier(service classes)-->client tier(Controllers).